# Cannot open form only when I have an on open form event handler in vba Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using Access 2016

I have a form that is opened from another form. It opens just fine if I do not have any custom code run when it opens. Otherwise, I receive a Run-time error Run-time error '2501', OpenForm action was canceled. This form needs to receive data from the form that opened it so I need the on open event handler.
By simply declaring the event handler with no code inside of it, I receive the error.

I.e.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
End Sub
```

By the sheer simplicity of my code, I am completely lost on what the issue could be and would appreciate any help.

Comment: When you jump to VBA editor, does you code compile? You want to ensure your code complies before you do anything. Messy code, or code that does not compile often is the issue here.  So before you run code, ensure that you do a debug->compile from the tools menu. During a typical day, you likely do this 100's of times, if not more.

Comment: I have been developing VBA for almost a year and I have never compiled it before nor even knew it was something I could do. So sure enough there was an issue with one of the names of my variables. This probably would have saved a lot of time on past issues but late is better than never. Thank you!